# Failing to install webkit via npm on Windows Subsystem for Linux (npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443)

Tags: ubuntu, npm, webkit, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to install [webpack-starter-master](https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter) via npm on my ubuntu terminal on windows. I've been getting numerous errors. The most recent is:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/BENIB/Desktop/programming/webpack-starter-master/npm-debug.log
```

Unfortunately I cannot post the log on here, because it would be too much code/too litle details to post. Instead, here's a [link to the log](https://shrib.com/#muzQbAl45pRQkI08GGxj)

Do you have any suggestions as to why that is and how to solve the error?

Comment: The cause is in this line `Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft`. WSL mimics Linux kernel but it shows different string in `/proc/version`.

Comment: Thank you @Biswapriyo. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hehe... Don't know. I'm C/C++ person.